# Enviar evento de pulsación de teclas con SendKeys.Send

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una aplicación ejecutandose que al pulsar las flechas izquierda y derecha juntas realiza una acción, pero necesito realizar la pulsación de esas teclas desde c# y no desde el teclado, lo he intentado con SendKeys e inputSimulator y nada

```
        SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}");
        SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
```

y también así:

```
SendKeys.Send("{LEFT}{RIGHT}");
```

de igual forma con sendWait y con input simulator

```
        InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
        sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LEFT);
        sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LEFT);
        sim.Keyboard.KeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
        sim.Keyboard.KeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
```

windows API tampoco me ha funcionado

Comment: estas usando webforms?

Comment: no, son forms normales, es una aplicación de escritorio